# простое наследование JAVA

Tags: java, наследование

Суть проста, есть два класса: `Main` и `Field`.

В классе `Field` есть метод, который просто рисует поле. Класс `Main`, где я пытаюсь реализовать метод `printMap ()` из класса `Field`, так как один статичный и другой нет, просто воспользоваться наследованием мне не Идея не дает, при этот насколько я знаю, статика используется только при написании утилит (за редким исключением), а метод `main ()` не статичным быть не может.

**Как грамотно оформить наследование**, если я хочу использовать методы других классов в методе `main ()`?

```
public class Main extends Field {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       super.printMap();
    }

}
```

второй класс

```
public class Field  {
    public int SIZE = 3;
    public char[][] map;

    public void printMap(){
        for(int i = 0; i<= SIZE; i++){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i =0; i <SIZE; i++){
            System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
            for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
                System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это вы намудрили. Просто из main (не обязательно отдельного класса) вызываете

```
new Field().printMap()
```

И без наследования! Оно здесь не нужно.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать композицию таким образом :

```
public class Main {

    private static final Field field = new Field();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       field.printMap();
    }
}
```